# UISlider.value logic / conditional

Tags: ios, logic, conditional-statements, uislider

Using this:

```
if (_sizeSlider.value <= 0.25) {
    //set to 256sq
    _exportSize = 256;
} else if ((_sizeSlider.value >= 0.26) && (_sizeSlider.value < 0.5)) {
    //set to 512
    _exportSize = 512;
} else if ((_sizeSlider.value >= 0.5) && (_sizeSlider.value < 0.75)) {
    //set to 1024
    _exportSize = 1024;
} else {
    //set to 1800
    _exportSize = 1800;
}
```

If the slider is exactly at 0.25, it thinks it's at 1. The problem does not happen at any other points.  Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gap between 0.25 and 0.26 which is not covered in your logic. This will fall through to the final case.

Comment: OK, I switched the case to look for greater than 0.25 instead of 0.26.  Was simple, not sure why I didn't try it first.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is to change the conditions as follow

```
<= 0.25

>0.25 to < 0.5

>=0.5 to < 0.75
```

just change this and your problem will be solved i think so 
Happy Coding :)